# How do i set to border to be as long as it needs to be?

Tags: html, css

I have code like the below. Instead of having the box stretch all the way to the right how do i make it only as long as it needs to be?

```
<html><body>
<pre style="{border-style:solid;}">A Sentence</pre>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use

```
<pre style="display: inline; border-style: solid">
```

(the `{}` don't belong in the style block by the way)

That would render the element as an inline object that doesn't occupy full width anymore, but **flows like normal text**. However, that way, the next following element will follow right next to the `pre`, and you may have to add `<br>` line breaks.

Answer (score 3):

Using an inner element would be a simple approach:

```
<html><body>
<pre><span style="border-style:solid;">A Sentence</span></pre>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2):

in this case you could make it `display: inline;`

Answer (score 1):

```
<html><body>
<pre><span style="border-style:solid;">A Sentence</span></pre>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

positioning the element should help

```
<html><body>
<pre style="border-style:solid; position:absolute;">A Sentence</pre>
</body></html>
```